# How do I use this? public <R extends IPCMessage> R sendAndGetResponse(IPCMessage msg)

Tags: java, generics

I've been writing Java swing GUI code for several years but the following syntax stumps me. I'm talking about the " < R extends IPCMessage > R" portion of the method below. I found this in a library another engineer wrote and I have no idea how to use it.

I'm very familiar with the other uses of generics but this one I don't know.

Can someone explain what is going on and how I can use it?

Thank you.

```
/**
 * Sends the specified IPC message to the process the IPC instance is
 * connected to
 * 
 * @param msg
 *            the IPC message to send
 * @return IPCMessageRx for the received response message if want_resp is
 *         true null if want_resp is true and no response was received
 *         within the timeout null if want_resp is false
 * @throws InvalidCastException if the return type doesn't match the actual
 * type of the response.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <R extends IPCMessage> R sendAndGetResponse(IPCMessage msg)
{
    logger.logTrace("IPClient::sendAndGetResponse: entered, msg = \"" + msg.toString() + "\"");

    // keep track of whether the message sent
    boolean msg_sent = send(msg);

    // if the message sent and a response is wanted, try to get one from the
    // received message buffer
    IPCMessage back = null;
    if (msg_sent == true)
    {
        back = receive(msg.getSequenceNumber());
    }

    if (back == null)
    {
        logger.logDebug("IPClient::send: exiting, back = null");
    }
    else
    {
        logger.logTrace("IPCClient::send: exiting, back != null");
    }

    return (R)back;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, basically the method lets you choose its return type. But because this is no safe way to use generics, a runtime exception may occur (as documented by the method), so one should always try to avoid such situations. However, sometimes it is very hard to accomplish and sometimes it is impossible at all.

Anyway, I think that this engineer was no Java expert, as he does not even adhere to the naming conventions (camel case variable names).

But now, here is what you can do with this method: Say, you have your own `IPCMessage` class:

```
class MyMessage implements IPCMessage {
  // ... whatever is needed here
}
```

Then, you need to know that the response of the message you want to send has the type `MyMessage` (which could be the tough part, but I can't tell this without knowing the rest of the code) and may call:

```
MyMessage response = sendAndGetResponse.<MyMessage> (messageToSend);
```

Comment: +1 for the good explanation. I would even add that you could then change the signature to `public <R extends IPCMessage> R sendAndGetResponse(R msg)` in that last case

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Thanks! What you suggested would probably even improve the safety of the method, because the type of response is related to the argument required. But on the other hand, it may be intended to have different types for the messages sent and received.

Comment: Totally true but then the cast definitely not safe to use and would sound more like a risky-not safe to maintain kind of method ;-)

Comment: Here is an example of how it has been used (I found this after posting): `SetKpiThresholdsResponse setResp = client.sendAndGetResponse(new SetKpiThresholdsRequest(HXMSAdminArg.SNNP_SET_KPI_THRESHOLDS, kpiThresholds));`

Answer (score 3):

To me, using the generic this way is useless. On the top of that, the InvalidCastException will never be thrown from within the method.

It would be better to use the following code and let the caller do the cast himself:

```
IPCMessage sendAndGetResponse(IPCMessage msg) {...}
```

Comment: You are right, the method is just hiding the cast. It could be left to the user to perform the cast himself wittingly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a generic method.  Basically, the signature of the method is saying that it will return whatever type of object you want it to return, as long as it extends IPCMessage.

Answer (score 2):

The method looks not good to me because it has no guarantee that the last cast is correct. I would therefore remove the SuppressWarning annotation.

These kind of methods can be used as following:

```
someObject.<SomeTypeExtendingICPMessage>sendAndGetResponse(msg);
```

But you have to be sure that the type you pass before the method is the one you will actually receive. This looks unsafe to me. It would make a lot more sense to either pass the type as a parameter of the method so that it can check the returned type safely.

Comment: The author of the question said that he has found this code in a library another engineer wrote. I'm afraid he may not have influence on this implementation, but you are right, it is fairly unsafe.

Comment: Yup, I over-assumed that the engineer was one of his colleagues or predecessor and that he could possibly make the change. This is also more like an advice on how the signature should have been written than a constraint to do it. Now, if he can't be sure of the return type, he can always ask for an ICPMessage and do the cast on the other end himself with the proper type checks.